# I am getting an error I am getting class cast exception in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have created a JSONArray and created RDD for this. When I was trying to map sqlContext.jsonRDD(rdd), I am getting the following error:

```
Error: application failed with exception
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 5, esu3v148.federated.fds): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at org.apache.spark.sql.json.JsonRDD$$anonfun$parseJson$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsonRDD.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$19.apply(RDD.scala:885)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$19.apply(RDD.scala:884)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$32.apply(SparkContext.scala:1534)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$32.apply(SparkContext.scala:1534)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Created JsonArray and used in the spark as detailed below:

```
JSONArray jsonResultArray = new JSONArray();
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseTest");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(60));
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

        if (!jsonResultArray.isEmpty()) {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            //JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.parallelize(jsonResultArray);

            DataFrame input = sqlContext.jsonRDD(sc.parallelize(jsonResultArray));
```

Please help me out, how to resolve this issue
Thanks.

Comment: What was the json String?

Answer (score 1):

`sqlContext.jsonRDD` [expects](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#jsonRDD(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD)) an argument of type `JavaRDD<java.lang.String>`.

JSONArray is a List of `org.json.simple.JSONObject`s, so `sc.parallelize(jsonResultArray)` creates a `JavaRDD<JSONObject>` - so an exception is thrown when this is passed to `jsonRDD`. This would normally be a compile-time error, but the compiler is mislead by the fact that `org.json.simple.JSONArray` extends the *generic* `List` (without explicit type), so this mismatch is only detected at runtime.

If you really have to use JSONArray, you'd have to map it into strings, before or after creating an RDD, for example:

```
final JavaRDD<JSONObject> jsonObjectRDD = sc.parallelize((List<JSONObject>) jsonResultArray);
final JavaRDD<String> jsonStringRDD = jsonObjectRDD.map(new Function<JSONObject, String>() {
     @Override
     public String call(JSONObject v) throws Exception {
          return v.toJSONString();
     }
});
DataFrame input = sqlContext.jsonRDD(jsonStringRDD);
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your email. I made changes as you said it throws compilation error hence I am sharing code: Please suggest me your change on where to amend. Quick reply would be a great help